# In differentiation as in dy/dx what do you call y and x?

Tags: mathematics

Like numerator / denominator, but for differentiation.

Comment: This is a math thing... right?

Comment: Tagged it as math, but I'm interested in the words so this seems like a better place.

Comment: I always called them "ex" and "why".

Comment: If it helps, they're generally called "infinitesimals" I don't seem to be able to find specific terms for the numerator and denominator... as it's still a division problem, so I'd argue the terms are still apt.

Comment: The `dependent` and `independent` variables respectively.  Technically speaking `dy/dx` isn't a fraction; it's a limit.

Comment: I think this is on topic here, but would be likely to get better answers, and to get answers more quickly, on the math Stack Exchange site. I think terminology questions are on topic there as well.

Comment: @A.Ellett that was what I was looking for, thanks. You should post it as the answer.

Comment: Here's a related question (it's half of yours) on Math that includes the suggestion *differentiand* (a neologism) for "that which is to be differentiated", by analogy with other Latin forms like *addend* = "that which is to be added" and *multiplicand* = "that which is to be multiplied". http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/656466/what-is-the-term-for-whatever-is-being-differentiated

Comment: @sumelic No mathematician would know what you're talking about if you said "differentiand".  The mathematical terminology for which such `-and` suffixes are applied refer to numbers.  In this case, a limit is applied to a function (not a number) to **derive** *another* function.

Comment: @A. Ellet: Can't functions be multiplied or added? I thought they could, but maybe not. And maybe the term "multiplicand" would not be used in that case. Anyway, I think the main reason a mathematician would probably be confused by "differentiand" is because, as I said, it isn't actually used; it's a neologism.

Comment: @sumelic I suppose.... though generally I would think mathematicians say "factor" in such a situation rather than "multiplicand".  There is no hard and fast rule or definition here regarding "multiplicand".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is predicated on the misconception that dy/dx is decomposable.

Comment: @Catija: No, `x` and `y` are not infinitesimals in `dy/dx`.

Comment: The whole d/dx semifraction is an operator, a function, itself, and could be represented by `D`, as in D (ln x) = l/x. The fractional notation was introduced by Leibnitz (Newton's notation used multiple dots) and has become traditional. But the fractional notation is just a mnemonic, and there really isn't a special name for y or x in the symbol.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`dy/dx` is a limit in which `y` represents the *dependent* variable and `x` the *independent* variable.  Since it is a limit, technically it is not a fraction.

> [image]

Comment: Is that really what it is, or just what it is equal to? I am not a mathematician, but if I remember correctly there are multiple ways to define differentiation, and not all of them require the concept of a limit.

Comment: @sumelic The derivative is defined by a limit.  It turns out that the derivative of many algebraically defined functions can easily be found by various algebraic rules.  But those rules are not what make derivatives what they are; the limit does.

Comment: @A. Ellet: I understand that the algebraic formulas for finding the derivative don't constitute a definition. But I thought somebody had also figured out a definition based on infinitesimals rather than limits.

Comment: @sumelic That is true.  But *infinitesimals* are a peculiar area of mathematics and do not form any part of standard mathematics education: whether in advanced mathematics or not.  Philosophically infinitesimals are interesting, but they can be viewed as problematic since they are not *constructive*.  So, yes, if you're interested in non-standard mathematics, it is possible to define derivatives differently.  But for practical, every day purposes, it's the limit definition which is actually useful.

Comment: For a beginner, this is a [course](http://ocw.mit.edu/resources/res-18-005-highlights-of-calculus-spring-2010/) to get answers to such questions

Comment: Another aside: nonstandard analysis (NSA) typically uses the same limit definition for derivatives. The difference is that NSA has more means of characterizing limits, and thus usually uses a different definition of limit.

Comment: Finally, the "not constructive" admonishment isn't really convincing; it's a description of "How do you go about proving consistency relative to ZFC?", not "How does one actually work with nonstandard anaylsis?". And I am led to believe that NSA has constructive foundations in constructive mathematics; nonconstructive aspects only appear when you're half-hearted about constructivism (e.g. using classical logic or Heyting logic and taking ZF as a foundation), and that even then there are workarounds if one really cares to do the extra work to work around it.

Comment: (correction of a  previous comment of mine) The words "independent" and "dependent" variables don't really have anything to do with Leibniz notation or the notion of differentiation. Using them here is sort of analogous to looking at "2/3" and saying that 2 is the even number and 3 is the odd number. (also, such usage of "independent" and "dependent" only applies to a limited perspective on variables)